# JApplet.getParameter returns null when passing large amount data to it

Tags: java, applet, japplet, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash

I have a web app.

At some point I do some data signing by smartCard and PKCS11. 
As Java can get access to the devices connected to the computer I use applet which is started by my web app.

Until now the data I wanted to sign (and some other stuff) were send to the applet via base64 encoded string provided as the applet parameter. Then in the applet, after user provided his passcode to the smart card, the data passed to the applet was signed and send back to the main web app.

I read the data passed to the app via:

```
String dataToDecode = this.getParameter("paramStr");
...
```

in the class extending JApplet.

Everything was OK, until I signed single documents.

Now the new requirement came up, and I need to sign ~100 documents at once.
The java code is adjusted to handle many documents, but when I try to sign the data the <del>applet crashes without any error, any sign, any exception, simply nothing and console window disappears.</del> *please see Edit 1*

1. I tried to increase the amount of memory available to JAVA via runtime parameters like:  -Xmx2048m    but it didn't help.
2. With trial and error I reached the limit of ~15 documents processed properly.
3. When I check the app without the applet, just running from Netbeans, I can sign the data of 100 documents without any problem, but I read base64encoded data from file during the test.

I suspect that the crash occurs when I try to read more then ~10 MB of data via

```
JApplet.getParameter("paramStr");
```

My questions are:

1. Are there any size limits for getParameter method of JApplet?
2. How can I detect / log what caused the crash?
3. Do you have any advice of how to deal with large amount of data in this case?

Thanks for your help

---

Edit 1:

In my comment I said I was sure that JVM crashes. **Now I discovered it is not**.

For some reason related to PKCS11 initialization / applets and JVM  I put System.Exit(0) in finally block of try/catch/finally. I generally avoid doing that.

I revised the code ... and there is no crash, simply method

```
JApplet.getParameter("paramStr")
```

returns null when large amount of data is passed into it and then I have exception.
I am sorry for "fooling" you in my first question. I was not aware of that.

So the main question right now:
Is there a limit of amount of data JApplet.getParameter("paramStr") can handle?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it _crashes_? Or does it  simply freeze until the data reading is finished?

Comment: I don't know the size limit of applet parameters, but it seems strange to me to use them for storing document data. You could try to load the documents from the server (co-located to the applet): http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=java:applet-read-from-server

Comment: @isnot2bad 
If I have no other option I will have to get the data from sever, but then I need to provide some kind of authorization, different approach compared to what I have right now. I generate applet code dynamically and put all the data-to-be-signed into the applet parameter. Applet data is generated based on pretty complex access rights matrix handled by web app. If there is no other option I will have to redesign the communication between applet and web app, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @norbi771 Of course, I don't know the architecture of your system. Maybe you can only pass some kind of "document key" to the applet via applet parameter. The document key then can be used by the applet to query the document from the server (e.g. via Servlet).

Comment: Please see question update, I was wrong JVM does not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be due to a browser bug. I suggest it is pointless trying to debug this - just sidestep the issue by requesting the data from the server via HTTP from the applet.